# Jest store.dispatch mock results in recursion loop and OOM

Tags: vue.js, unit-testing, jestjs, vuex, store

#### Context:

We have a custom timer which should log users off after 15 mins of inactivity.  The timer's `performLogoff` function calls `store.dispatch` to the user module's logout action to clean up the rest of state and localforage in our Vue.js app.

#### Issue(s):

- the test mocks `store.dispatch` and calls `performLogoff`
- performLogoff calls `store.dispatch` for logoff
- issue 1: code still goes inside of `user/logout`
- subsequent issue 2: as soon as it hits the first `store.dispatch` in `user/logout`, it recurses down into itself and never terminates

Since these are all async, the test is marked as green / passed, but it doesn't terminate.  Instead it continues to recurse and ends up out of memory, then aborts (see output below).

[image: Test passes]

#### Question:

- How to properly mock the `store.dispatch` so that we can validate that it is successfully called, without it getting stuck in this loop?

###### timer.spec.js

```js
import store from '@/store'
import userStore from '@/store/modules/user'

jest.mock('@/store')

...

  let t

  beforeAll(() => {
    t = new Timer(...)
  })

...

  it('should be able to log user off', async () => {
    jest.requireMock('@/store')
    jest.requireMock('@/store/modules/user')

    let count = 0

    let mockCommit = () => {
      count += 1
    }
    localforage.removeItem = jest.fn(() => { return null })

    store.dispatch = jest.fn(async () => {
      await userStore.actions.logout({ commit: mockCommit })
    })

    return t.performLogoff().then(() => {
      expect(count).toBe(1)
    })
  })
```

###### timer.js

```js
  ...

  async performLogoff() {
    await store.dispatch('user/logout')
  }
  ...
```

###### store/modules/user.js

```js
...

async logout({ commit }) {
    await localforage.removeItem('token')
    await localforage.removeItem('user_details')
    ...
    commit('SET_TOKEN', '')
    commit('SET_USER_DETAILS', '')
    ...
    store.dispatch('module2/setDetails', '')
    store.dispatch('module3/setOtherDetails', '')
    window.localStorage.clear()
  }
...
```

###### Test console output

```sh
<--- Last few GCs --->

[50123:0x7fd300008000]   152839 ms: Mark-sweep (reduce) 4081.6 (4143.1) -> 4081.1 (4143.6) MB, 5073.3 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.290, current mu = 0.001) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed
[50123:0x7fd300008000]   157867 ms: Mark-sweep (reduce) 4082.3 (4143.8) -> 4081.9 (4144.6) MB, 5023.3 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.168, current mu = 0.001) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed


<--- JS stacktrace --->

FATAL ERROR: Reached heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 0x10f4cb70c node::Abort() [/usr/local/bin/node]
 2: 0x10f4cc73d node::OnFatalError(char const*, char const*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 3: 0x10f62b88d v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 4: 0x10f62b838 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 5: 0x10f76f9e7 v8::internal::Heap::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(char const*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 6: 0x10f76e9e5 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 7: 0x10f77ad0d v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithLightRetrySlowPath(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 8: 0x10f77ad6c v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFailSlowPath(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 9: 0x10f752308 v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject(int, bool, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin) [/usr/local/bin/node]
10: 0x10fa00771 v8::internal::Runtime_AllocateInYoungGeneration(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
11: 0x10f3304b9 Builtins_CEntry_Return1_DontSaveFPRegs_ArgvOnStack_NoBuiltinExit [/usr/local/bin/node]
12: 0x10f3a8879 Builtins_NewStrictArgumentsElements [/usr/local/bin/node]
13: 0x1178a89d9 

Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT)
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated the test with `mockImplementationOnce` and it seems to work:

```js
...
  it('should be able to log user off', async () => {
    let count = 0

    let mockCommit = () => {
      count += 1
    }
    localforage.removeItem = jest.fn(() => {
      return null
    })

    store.dispatch = jest.fn().mockImplementationOnce(async () => {
      await userStore.actions.logout({ commit: mockCommit })
    })

    return t.performLogoff().then(() => {
      expect(count).toBe(1)
    })
  })
...
```

This allows the mock to be called the first time, and all of the subsequent `store.dispatch` calls in the user module don't get mocked, stopping the recursive loop.

Still open to other answers / better ways of testing this!